# Swift/Carthage - Can I get it to compile to different version?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, carthage

I have both Xcode `7.3.1` and Xcode `8.2.1` installed, as I'm taking over a project that was compiled with Xcode `7.3`. Carthage is being used to pull in RealmSwift, but it's compiling it to Swift 3 and I'm getting the error:

> "Module file was created by a newer version of the compiler"

I tried using the following command, but I believe it's still compiling (locally) to Swift 3.

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

Is it possible to pull in 3rd party frameworks and compile them to Swift 2?